# Slow PDF viewing from my site

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, pdf

I'm running iss 7.0 on server 2008 SP 2. When I open a 20 mb pdf in IE with the adobe plugin or chrome it's unusable slow. Right click and save is near instant.

IE is slow enough that a 20 MB pdf takes over 10 minutes to open. It's happening from inside the network and from my remote PC and from the local machine accessing itself. Chrome is a bit faster but still unusable slow. This happens on at least 2 PDF files ,the two largest on our site.

I think the cause is that in **IE** I get an initial 10MB download then the rest of the file gets downloaded as a bunch of http 206 requests that are 16k in size

example header:

```
--request
GET http://www.nanaimo.ca/assets/Departments/Parks~Rec~Culture/Leisure~Guide/AG_Fall2013_Winter2014.pdf HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Range: bytes=14696448-14712831
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)
Host: www.nanaimo.ca
Connection: Keep-Alive

--response

HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Range: bytes 14696448-14712831/15315529
Last-Modified: Mon, 30 Sep 2013 22:01:02 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "dd519f8d28bece1:0"
Date: Tue, 17 Dec 2013 17:30:02 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 16384
```

Interestingly if I'm running fiddler (web traffic capture tool) when I start IE then it just does the full request and the pdf loads instantly (1gb connection to server).

**Edit**
Changed url to a url that's more noticeable as the first url was only 10 seconds vs the expected 4 seconds. The larger file is much slower. Also increased note that this is an issue with IE and adobe reader.

Comment: It loads in about 5-8 seconds for me, over the internet. So, it's not your server.

Comment: Once it downloads, it opens very fast for me. Mere seconds. Thanks for putting the actual URL for us to test.

Comment: What browsers are you two using? What version of adobe?

Comment: And did it open in the browser or in a separate window

Comment: I've confirmed that the bylaw file (link above) is rather fast remotely but the larger http://www.nanaimo.ca/assets/Departments/Parks~Rec~Culture/Leisure~Guide/AG_Fall2013_Winter2014.pdf is much slower.

Comment: Also the first page loads fine. It's the last pages that fail.

Comment: So it might be a firewall issue slowing it down.

Comment: The link you posted in comments loads for me in under 10 seconds. I have no idea why you think a firewall would be responsible for any aspect of this. Can you explain your reasoning?

Comment: I'm using chrome, it opens in a chrome window.

Comment: The issue turned out to be that in IE and the adobe plugin It downloads the file in 16 kb chunks. (chrome uses much bigger chunks) and the firewall (now partly disabled) scans each just for malware and vulnerabilities. Then the virus scanner scans it. Then a few other checks happen to the packet and it finally leaves our subnet.